# How do I delete elements using grep or map?

Tags: perl

How do I use `grep` or `map` to delete elements from an array or reference to array? I’m having problems using `splice` to remove one or more elements from a reference to array and would like to see whether `grep` or `map` can offer me a better solution.

```
@removedElements = grep /test/, @array;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are saying `"array or reference array"` like it was two different things. Which is confusing.

I assume that since you have named your array `@removedElements`, what you are trying to ask is how to *remove* the elements from `@array` and put them in `@removedElements`.

```
@removedElements = grep /test/, @array;   
@array           = grep ! /test/, @array;
```

A simple negation of the test will yield either list. You can also do a loop:

```
my (@removedElements, @rest);
for (@array) {
    if (/test/) {
        push @removedElements, $_;
    } else {
        push @rest, $_;
    }
}
```

Which has the benefit of fewer checks being performed.

In order to use `splice`, you would need to keep track of indexes, and I'm not sure its worth it in this case. It certainly would not make your code easier to read. Similarly, I doubt `map` would be much more useful than a regular loop.

Answer (score 9):

Use `grep` if you know the elements you want to keep.

```
my @keepers = grep /interesting/, @array;
```

If instead you have a reference to an array, then write

```
my @keepers = grep /interesting/, @$arrayref;
```

Note that this does not modify the array.

The process is similar with `map`. Given a test that rejects elements, write

```
my @keepers = map /do not want/ ? () : $_, @array;
```

Invert the sense of the test with

```
my @keepers = map /interesting/ ? $_ : (), @array;
```

Answer (score 2):

You might also like the `extract_by` function from [`List::UtilsBy`](http://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aUtilsBy). It is similar to grep, except that it removes the items from the passed array.

```
use List::UtilsBy qw( extract_by );

# some values in @array

my @removed = extract_by { m/test/ } @array;

# Matching elements will now be removed from @array and appear in @removed.
```